# How do I add a bootstrap table on a typescript react document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript-typings

I am trying to create an app that when a link is clicked, database info is showed. Said database connection is specified on a spring app, but that does not matter. I've created the model of a table using bootstrap on a html, which would be a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src=""></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js%22 crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js%22 crossorigin="
        anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22 crossorigin=" anonymous">
</head>

<style>
    th {
        text-align: center;
    }

    td {
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    h4 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #hijo{
       text-align: right; 
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" ></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><h1>Hijos</h1></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div id="hijo">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAgregar">
                        Agregar Hijo
                    </button>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalAgregar">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Agrega un Hijo</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Chicos</th>
                                            <th>Chicas</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>                                                
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Chicos</th>
                    <th>Chicas</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Borrar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                Editar
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                     <tr>
                                                        <th>Chicos</th>
                                                        <th>Chicas</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>                                                
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value ="2">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>                                                            
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value ="1">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
                                Borrar
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Atención</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h4>El registro será borrado.¿Continuar?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                Editar
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Chicos</th>
                                                    <th>Chicas</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value ="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value ="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
                                Borrar
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Atención</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h4>El registro será borrado.¿Continuar?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                Editar
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Chicos</th>
                                                    <th>Chicas</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value ="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value ="2">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
                                Borrar
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Atención</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h4>El registro será borrado.¿Continuar?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

That's a lot of code, but it's just an example of what I want to show in the end. I'm having troubles adapting this code into the typescript react app, where classes like    div class="container"     do not exist.

Here is the class that would get the data from the database :

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import CSS from 'csstype';
import * as ReactBootStrap from "react-bootstrap";


type Hijo = {
  id: number
  chicos: number
  chicas: number
}

type Rol={
  id:number
  rol:string
}

class Hijos extends React.Component {

  readonly urlLogin = "http://localhost:8081/user";
  readonly urlHijos = "http://localhost:8081/api/hijos";
  hijos:Array<Hijo>=[];
  hijo:Hijo;
  token:string;


  componentDidMount() {
   
    this.autenticar()
    
  }

   autenticar=()=>{
   axios.post(`${this.urlLogin}?username=pepe&password=1234`).then((response: any) => {
    
    this.token= response.data.token;

    axios.get(this.urlHijos,{headers:{'Authorization':this.token}}).then((response:any)=>{
      
      this.hijos=response.data;
      
      
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(this.token);
    })
  })
  return this.token;
}
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        {this.hijos.map(hijo => <h1>Id: {hijo.id} Chicos: {hijo.chicos} Chicas: {hijo.chicas}</h1>)}
        <ReactBootStrap.Table bordered>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Larry the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </ReactBootStrap.Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Hijos;
```

On the upper side of the code is the configuration to connect via username and password, followed by the link, and in the render(), the first line appears the code to get the database info. The rest is an attempt to create a table, but it appears to me without the borders.

Finally, here is the main app:

```
import {BrowserRouter,Link,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Hijos from './Hijos';
import Dos from './Dos';
import Uno from './Uno';
let nombre:string="pepe";
function App() {
 
  return (
    <div >
    
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/uno" className="rojo">uno</Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to="/hijos">cargos</Link>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/uno" ><Uno texto={nombre}/></Route>
       <Route path="/hijos" component={Hijos}/>
     </Switch>
     
     </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It has two links that return below a text, when clicking "cargos" the table would appear, without the borders, and if you click a second time, the database information appears. I don't know why that works like that, but that isn't the focus of my question.

How can I adapt my html to the typescript react file?

Comment: Since you're using react-bootstrap, just look at examples on their website. For instance where you had `<div class="container">` in plain HTML, with react-bootstrap you can use the `<Container>` component.

Comment: Yeah I've just seen that I could put the container on the tsx file as tag ReactBootStrap.Container, but it still doesn't format the table with the borders done on the html file.

Comment: You have that `bordered` property on the table. I quickly ran just the table rendering and I could see the border.

Comment: Did it show it up on the main app? Or just the HTML?

Comment: all I did was `import { Table } from "react-bootstrap"; const App = () => (<Table bordered> ...the rest of your example here`